# Eisenstein series and the Kronecker limit theorem

Tags: eisenstein-series, analytic-number-theory

It is well known that the first Kronecker limit theorem gives the Laurent expansion of the Eisenstein series $E(z,s)$ over $SL(2,Z)$ at $s=1$; see, for example, Serge Lang's book Elliptic Curves, Section 20.4.

My question is, is there an analogous formula for the Eisenstein series over congruence subgroups? This seems a natural question and I believe that it must be hidden somewhere in the literature, but I cannot find a reference.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Remark: Thanks to Anweshi's help, we can find the following papers.

To be more precise, the above mentioned papers are

1. MR0318065 (47 #6614) Goldstein, Larry Joel, Dedekind sums for a Fuchsian group. I. Nagoya Math. J. 50 (1973), 21--47. 10D10 (10G05). [This paper gives the generalization of Kronecker's first limit formula to Eisenstein series over a Fuchsian group of the first kind at any cusp.]

MR0347739 (50 #241) Goldstein, Larry Joel, Errata for ``Dedekind sums for a Fuchsian group. I'' (Nagoya Math. J. 50 (1973), 21--47). Nagoya Math. J. 53 (1974), 235--237. 10D15 (10G05)

1. MR0347740 (50 #242) Goldstein, Larry Joel, Dedekind sums for a Fuchsian group. II. Nagoya Math. J. 53 (1974), 171--187. 10D15 (10G05). [This paper gives the generalization of Kronecker's second limit formula for "generalized Eisenstein series".]

Comment: I think you're looking for the theory of automorphic forms.

Comment: Yes, but in a very classical language.

Comment: The book of Rademacher on analytic number theory may help with background on Dedekind sums. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a generalization. It was done by Larry Joel Goldstein, in the paper "Dedekind sums for a Fuchsian group". The paper has two parts and was published in the Nagoya Journal in around 1973-74.